# CarrierWave upload to Flickr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, flickr

Can I upload image with CarrierWave to Flickr?

I use `gem 'flickraw'` but is there any posibility to bind it with CarrierWave

Answer (score 1):

I've built a library for this purpose. You can find it on Github - [carrierwave-flickr](https://github.com/Hirurg103/carrierwave-flickr)

Use the following code to configure carrierwave to work with flickraw

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.flickr_credentials = {
    key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    secret: 'YOUR_SECRET',
    oauth_token: 'YOUR_TOKEN',
    oauth_token_secret: 'YOUR_TOKEN_SECRET'
  }
end
```

and in your uploader

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :flickr
end
```

Comment: Try to provide a detailed answer (what is needed to be done) and then link to a library or package, etc.

Comment: @masoud there is a link to library in my answer. The installation details can be found on the library homepage. Should I copy them to my answer?